# define variables in WndProc function

Tags: winapi

it is acceptable to declare/define a variable in the WndProc function. as this code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

switch (message)
{
...
```

the question whether it's good.
Because the program enters into this function, thousands of times every minute, and every time these variables are redefined, and again destroyed, maybe it is better to define these variables outside the WndProc function, in the class, thus saving time and resources?

Comment: The real cost is not in allocating memory for the variables (which assuming they do not have constructors or destructors, is quite inexpensive). The real cost is in the stack usage. Since the WndProc can be highly recursive, you don't want to chew up a lot of stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because the program enters into this function, thousands of times every minute, and every time these variables are redefined, and again destroyed, maybe it is better to define these variables outside the `WndProc` function, in the class, thus saving time and resources?

As far as time and resources go, it makes little difference. These are local variables, stored on the stack. The entire stack is already reserved when your thread is created, and the memory for these variables is committed no later than the first time this procedure is executed. So this means that, for `switch` conditions that don't refer to these variables, you likely won't be able to measure the difference in runtime or resource needs caused by the presence of the variables.

Raymond points out that `WndProc` can be called recusively. If you have a lot of local variables in your `WndProc`, the resulting stack usage can be sub-optimal. I still can't imagine any real world application where the bottleneck was stack usage of `WndProc`.

Having said that, a `WndProc` method which is one big switch statement containing all the variables is bad practice. You don't want to pollute the local namespace of this function with lots of different variables. I suggest you make a separate handler function for each message that you want to handle in the window procedure.

Finally, you suggest declaring these variables in the class. Don't do this. Local variables are always preferred where possible. It's certainly going to be possible to declare these variables as locals. Although they should be locals of the separate handler functions that `WndProc` calls.

Answer (score 1):

When local variables are 'created', room is allocated to fit all of them onto the stack and their constructor is called. If there is no constructor, I believe the default action is to 'zero' the fields, although I'm not 100% sure about that.

However, this can be achieved in perhaps a dozen of instructions. This effect is negligible in comparison to other operations and especially system calls. If you are still concerned about the time spent by different routines in your program, I'd advise you to use a tool like [gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html).

Comment: Default action is not to zero the fields. Reserving stack space for these variables is a no-op

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, indeed fields are not zeroed. You must mean that the _constructor_ of these variables is a no-op? Reserving stack space definitely isn't, it moves the stack pointer to account for the space that is needed. Disassemble a simple function with some local variable and you will see an instruction like `sub $0x14,%esp`, reserving - in this case - 0x14 bytes of memory on the stack for the local variables.

Comment: But there will be an instruction of that form no matter what. And a single `sub` is not very far from being a no-op. Especially when you consider what has happened to get that message to you, and what will happen for the rest of that message's life.